# Javascript, saving user details to a database

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I'm teaching myself some web development on the side, and just for fun I'm trying to build a small e-commerce website for my gf (She might actually use it for a business idea if I don't get side tracked and not finish in time)

So I've managed to build a basic front end with html, css and javascript... The 1st hurdle I've run into is saving basic user details to a database, could someone please guide me in the right direction on what would be the quickest and easiest way to accomplish this.

The only other programming language I have a decent grasp of (certification level) is Java

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look on https://vaadin.com, it's a java web framework so you could use only java to serve the page and manage the user data. But i suggest you do PHP files which do the database work, then you sent the data with ajax from the website (or "POST") to the PHP files. Sql integration with PHP is very easy and straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the best way to store user details is probably to NOT store them at all lol. If you can use any third party authentication like Facebook or google, i really think you should give it a try. If you really feel like doing your own login/sign up. It's gonna be in the back-end. Using PHP is easy if you don't have any experience in that kind of stuff.

[This is an example of something not too bad](http://www.codingcage.com/2015/04/php-login-and-registration-script-with.html)

hope it answers your question. If not, let me know and i can give you some more details !

Answer (score 0):

This question can not be answered in a few sentences. But have a look:

Javascript is executed on the client side while PHP for example is executed on the server. You need to send a so called `HTTP Request` to your PHP server using javascript. This can be done with `jQuery` via `ajax()` function or using native JS like:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "myTutorials.txt";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var myArr = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    console.log(myArr);
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_http.asp

but i strongly recommend u to use jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

What happens during such a http request? The Client (your PC) sends data via an URL to the webserver and u receive it in the response. (have a look at the response in your development tool)

greetings